# What happens to trustline to account that has been merged?

Tags: accounts, trustline

If asset issuer account has been merged with another account what happens to assets by the account and trustlines created to that account?

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you want to merge account `X` to account `Y`.

X cannot hold any offers or trustlines (therefore, no assets), according to the source code.

https://github.com/stellar/go/blob/e0ffe19f58879d3c31e2976b97a5bf10e13a337b/xdr/xdr_generated.go#L3873

---

*Otherwise, the operation will fail with `"op_has_sub_entries"`.*

And account X will be charged 100 stroops txFee, and seq_num += 1.

```
{
  "type": "https://stellar.org/horizon-errors/transaction_failed",
  "title": "Transaction Failed",
  "status": 400,
  "detail": "The transaction failed when submitted to the stellar network. The `extras.result_codes` field on this response contains further details.  Descriptions of each code can be found at: https://www.stellar.org/developers/learn/concepts/list-of-operations.html",
  "extras": {
    "envelope_xdr": "AAAAAAWb/DbpS8kPxCqdXLV+Az4ibTOwxPLFDqbAmDc3/vG/AAAAZACD6qIAAAACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAFZy28/5fhGoXqWueZaco8fRv25qq2EslnODyi8naNNMAAAAAAAAAATf+8b8AAABA/tFZ+/M6he+cbYoLXnBOkT9Hzh0AsliSXNu0vrzbBLHNKIUwAAxhafcPu49EFOKk7/9RooD2Q6zchw8X3pRSDQ==",
    "result_codes": {
      "transaction": "tx_failed",
      "operations": [
        "op_has_sub_entries"
      ]
    },
    "result_xdr": "AAAAAAAAAGT/////AAAAAQAAAAAAAAAI/////AAAAAA="
  }
}
```

---

[EDIT]

So, if you want to merge X to Y, you need to destroy all its trustlines and offers first.

---

[Additional info]

If you possess balance > 0 for an asset and try to directly `Change Trust` to 0, you will experience `"op_invalid_limit"` error. You need to transfer away every asset until its balance is 0, and then `Change Trust` every asset to `TrustLimit=0`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot merge accounts that have subentries (trustlines, offers, data).

Subentries can be found by going to `https://horizon.stellar.org/accounts/<your_account_id>` and searching for the `subentry_count` field.

You can find more information about the merge operation in the docs [here](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/list-of-operations.html#account-merge).